# How to add rows dynamically to the GridView based on the TextBox value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview

I have a TextBox, GridView and Button such as "txtCount", "gvCount" and "btnCount".

The gvCount has the following columns

```
<Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblRTDetailID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RTDetailID") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assy. No.">
      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtgvAssyNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AssyNo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Position">
      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlgvPos" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Position") %>'>
      </asp:DropDownList>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

If the TextBox "txtCount" has the text "10". While clicking the Button "btnCount", 10 rows would be added to the GridView. Likewise, I need to add rows to the GridView based on the TextBox value. How to do this?

Comment: And what should the values be in those 10 rows?

Comment: @Magnus: All the TextBox values should be empty and DropDownlist should show the SelectedValue = "-1";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gv.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(0, int.Parse(txtCount.Value))
               .Select (e => new 
               { 
                  RTDetailID = "", 
                  AssyNo = "", 
                  Position = "-1"
               });
gv.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand, you want to add new rows to a gridview, in your code-behind right?

Get the TextBox value, convert to int, and loop with a common for using this: http://www.stellarpc.com/articles/board.aspx?id=33

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a datatable. Using a for loop starting from 0 to textbox's text-1 add datarows to the datatable. Then set the datatable as the Gridview datasource.